# Rudin's theorem 6.6

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The theorem states:
$ f $ is Riemann integrable if and only if for $ \epsilon >0 $ there exists a partition $ P $ such that $ U(P,f)-L(P,f)<\epsilon$.

($U(P,f) $ denotes the upper sum and and $ L(P,f) $ the lower sums)

What is the significance of this?

Comment: No, this is not the same. Almost never can you have $ L $ and $ U $ coincide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "significance". To me, the significance is that unlike the definition of Riemann integrability, which requires arbitrary evaluation points on arbitrary sequences of partitions whose mesh size tend to zero, this result (the equivalence of *Riemann* and *Darboux* integration) tells us that we need only consider upper and lower sums on a single sequence of partitions. It makes checking Riemann integrability much easier than using the definition, which is intentionally formulated to be very strict.

Comment: thank you,yes I wasn't sure why this would be better to use in place of the definition but I see why now

Comment: Doe this theorem also hold for a constant function on $[a,b]$?
If the function is contant, then you cannot find an $\epsilon>0$ because for any partition $L(P,f)=U(P,f)$. Is this right?

Comment: @julian.marr Sure, a constant function is Riemann integrable. But then that would be just as easy to check with the other definition, since the Riemann sum for any tagged partition would always be the same, too.

Comment: Thank you Ian, I see now where my mistake was: if $L(P,f)=U(P,f)$, then $U(P,f)-L(P,f)=0<\epsilon$. Thank you very much. Your interpretation of "we need only consider upper and lower sums on a single sequence of partitions" is very enlightening.